# node.js+mongoose - How to implement matching (like order matching)?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, mongodb, mongoose, matching

I have a node.js+mongoose rest api. I have two schemas which needs to be matched as and when a new entry is added to either one or on a timely basis. The matching will compare the whole set of documents with a set of paramters. Let's say, for example, i have the below 2 schemas -

```
Males: {
age: Number,
location: String,
language: String,
matchedFemales: []
}

Females: {
age: Number,
location: String,
language: String,
matchedMales: []
}
```

Now, i have to take a collection and scroll through all the documents and find matches. I have lots of parameters as matching criteria, but let us take for an example, language, location should be same and the age is almost equal (+ or - 1 year). Like below -

```
Males: [{
    id: 1001,
    age: 20,
    location: London,
    language: English,
    matchedFemales: [2001,2002]
    },
    {
    id: 1002,
    age: 30,
    location: London,
    language: English,
    matchedFemales: []
    },
    {
    id: 1003,
    age: 20,
    location: Madrid,
    language: Spanish,
    matchedFemales: [2003]
    }]


Females: [{
    id: 2001,
    age: 20,
    location: London,
    language: English,
    matchedFemales: [1001]
    },
    {
    id: 2002,
    age: 19,
    location: London,
    language: English,
    matchedFemales: [1001]
    },
    {
    id: 2003,
    age: 20,
    location: Madrid,
    language: Spanish,
    matchedFemales: [1003]
    }]
```

How to perform this matching and how to store the matches?

1. Should i iterate though each document in Male collection and find matches in the Female collection and update it? IF so, i plan to have a service do it and call this service every X minutes. This job will be time and resource consuming (as it has to go through each document and find matches) but will be run for a definite number of times per day. If its every 5 mins, then it will be run only 12 times in an hour.
2. Instead of matching all documents in LHS against all documents in RHS, as and when a record is getting inserted, i can find matches just for that document and update it. This method will be less time & resource consuming than the previous method, but it will be run more number of times i.e., for every insert/update this has to be done.

Or is there any other elegant way to do this?

P.S - If this question seems inappropriate, kindly direct me to the right source for reference or consultation.

Comment: You can use Mongoose Middleware to execute a function before save or update to catch new documents / updates to documents http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: It's a big of a shame that this would be a descent problem to describe approaches to if your phrasing of it was not 1.) As broad as it is without focusing on a specific set of "matching criteria" which is sadly missing from the question. 2.) As primarily opinion based as it is by just throwing out a list of alternates without describing the actual constraints and needs. In this form, I feel the question will just get closed, or otherwise return answers of little real use. The only advice I can give other than "narrow down the question", is Single collection. Not two. "gender": "male/female"

Comment: to piggyback on what @BlakesSeven said. You'd then use a single matches array with type set to unique object ids of the same model. Combine that with my above comment and you could easily do what you want.

Comment: @Blakes Seven, I'm sorry the question was so broad. I guess i had lots of questions on this and dumped everything out. I have added an example of how i have planned the matching now. Along with example matching criteria. I just want to know the methodology for this matching. Like which will be less time-consuming. A timely job which will iterate through all documents vs all documents will take more time but run less number of times relatively. Option 2 will take less time but run more number of times. Hope i have put my confusion clearly.